# Pass variable as Type c#

Tags: c#, .net, types, dbcontext

I'm doing a new API in .NET 6 with a custom dbcontext because I need to use Shadow Properties, wherever i'm reading a XML file where I store the information like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Container>
    <Properties>
        <Property>
            <Entity>Enterprise</Entity>
            <Name>Actor</Name>
            <TypeEntity>String</TypeEntity>
        </Property>
    </Properties>
</Container>
```

And I need to use the "Property" to build shadow properties in my model like this:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"GraphQL\CustomProperties", "Properties.xml");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("Properties").Descendants("Property"))
            {
                var Entity = element.Element("Entity").Value;
                var CustomType = element.Element("TypeEntity").Value;
                builder.Entity<Foo>().Property<string>(element.Element("Name").Value).IsRowVersion();
            }
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
```

I need to get "CustomType" and send it into parameter Property like this:

```
builder.Entity<Foo>().Property<CustomType>(element.Element("Name").Value).IsRowVersion();
```

But when I do this appears the next message:
**"CustomType Is a variable but is used like a type"**
Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: What else can be there instead of `string`? If the set of available types is short you could have a switch covering all types.

Comment: I tried that way, now I have only 3 types, but i was suggested to find another way to do it cause in future the project is going to use a lot of them

Comment: What do you mean by "custom DbContext"? As opposed to a "non-custom" DbContext? But **all** DbContexts are "custom" in some way or another because they're configured to match a specific database design.

Answer (score 1):

There's [another overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder.property?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-property(system-type-system-string)) for that `Property` method you're invoking that takes a `Type` argument instead of a generic argument.

You'll need to find the `System.Type` that corresponds to the value of your `CustomType`, and then call that overload.

```
var customTypeName = element.Element("TypeEntity").Value;
var customType = customTypeName switch {
    "String" => typeof(string), // add other possibilities here.
};
builder.Entity<Foo>().Property(customType, element.Element("Name").Value).IsRowVersion();
```

Comment: Alternatively, just doing `new Type(customTypeName)` should also work (wrapped in a `try{} catch` block, ofc).

Comment: Just a suggestion for OP, this mapping of a string into a type can be set in configuration. Your boss could be happy with that.

Comment: @Dai: `Type` is an abstract type: you can't construct it just by providing a type name like that. `Type.GetType()` requires a full type name (`System.String` instead of just `String`), but I'm not sure I'd recommend that. The input XML may need to limit the types that are allowable, and probably shouldn't be coupled to the .NET type names specifically.